# Stackoverflow error in repeated loading of listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

**What is happening :** On repeated loading of this `ListView` I am getting the log errors as below (I counted 10 times). How to resolve this?

***I am having these codes in adapter of a listview***

```
    viewHolder.btnPhoneId.setTag(R.string.tag_phoneNo,_searchModel.get(position).getPhno());


    if (_searchModel.get(position).getProfleImage() == null || _searchModel.get(position).getProfleImage().equals("") || _searchModel.get(position).getProfleImage().length()==0) {
        //imgPerPicOneId.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_profile_image));
        Picasso.with(context)
        .load(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4))
        .resize(100, 100)
        .centerCrop().into(viewHolder.profileImage);
    }else{
        String finalImg=context.getResources().getString(R.string.image_api)+_searchModel.get(position).getProfleImage().replace("Windhyaapp/","");
        Picasso.with(context)
        .load(finalImg)
        .transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4))
        .resize(100, 100)
        .centerCrop().into(viewHolder.profileImage);
    }


    //For Favorite icon
    if(_searchModel.get(position).getFav()==false){
        viewHolder.btnFavId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
        viewHolder.btnFavId.setTag("heart_grey");
    }else{
        viewHolder.btnFavId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_blue);
        viewHolder.btnFavId.setTag("heart_blue");
    }

    //For Phone icon
    if(_searchModel.get(position).getBid()==false){
        viewHolder.btnPhoneId.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.btnPhoneId.setTag("INVISIBLE");
    }else{
        viewHolder.btnPhoneId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.btnPhoneId.setTag("VISIBLE");
    }

    viewHolder.btnFavId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                String favTag=viewHolder.btnFavId.getTag().toString();
                String phnoTag=viewHolder.btnPhoneId.getTag().toString();
                String serviceProviderId=viewHolder.serviceProviderId.getTag().toString();

                if(favTag.equalsIgnoreCase("heart_grey")){
                    viewHolder.btnFavId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_blue);
                    viewHolder.btnFavId.setTag("heart_blue");

                    prepJSON("heart_blue",serviceProviderId);
                    //new LongOperationFavUnfav().execute("");
                    LongOperationFavUnfav();

                }else{
                    viewHolder.btnFavId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                    viewHolder.btnFavId.setTag("heart_grey");
                    prepJSON("heart_grey",serviceProviderId);
                    //new LongOperationFavUnfav().execute("");
                    LongOperationFavUnfav();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

### Log:

```
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661): Process: com.windhyaworks, PID: 29661
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.isPremultiplied(Bitmap.java:1056)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1086)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:844)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:490)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.draw(PicassoDrawable.java:96)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1032)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14508)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3363)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2465)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3358)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14511)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3824)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14511)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1057)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14511)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14511)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:509)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
01-15 20:06:49.929: E/AndroidRuntime(29661):    at android.vie
```

Comment: Looks like your view hierarchy is too deep. The trace shows many, many viewgroups being traversed before even reaching the listview.

Comment: @laalto ........... Yes my view hierarchy is too deep  but my layout is complicated .... how to make proper matching to come up with a solution ...... is there a way to keep this hierarchy and avoid crashing  ?

Comment: Not really. Also the list view item hierarchy shown above the `AbsListView` has one or two nesting levels too many. Usually you can replace nested layouts with a well-thought `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @laalto ............ it still crashes even if i remove all the linear layouts and replace with single relative layout ... can the issue be related to PICASSO and the other two images i am using ?

Comment: Each nested method call takes up some stack and if you have too many nested calls you'll eventually run out of stack. Your view hierarchy depth is the main driver to the number of nested method calls here. Picasso doesn't contribute much there.

Comment: @laalto .... But as i said ... i had just tried with single relative layout with all the views inside .... still i got the same error as i showed in LOg ? ...... i am sure now there is another possibility